# Should women marry the rapist according to Islam?

Tags: nikah, sharia

I'm so confused. Is there any source for this ruling from Hadith or Quran.

1. [link 1](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2114884/Moroccan-girl-16-kills-judge-forced-marry-man-RAPED-her.html)
2. [link 2](http://www.frontpagemag.com/2013/frank-crimi/afghan-woman-forced-to-marry-her-rapist/)

Is this part of the Islamic sharia Law?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. Please include this specific ruling within the question to foil link-rots. Also go through [ask].

Answer (score 5):

It is clearly not supported by islam.
Here are some hadiths.

> “'Truly Allah has totally forbidden disobedience (and the subsequent
>   hurt) to mothers, burying alive daughters, with-holding the rights of
>   others, and demanding that which is not your right.” (Hadith Muslim
>   4257. Recorded by Mughirah b. Shuba). - See more at: http://www.therevival.co.uk/forced-arranged-love-secret-marriages#sthash.7RGlJhRY.dpuf3

and

> Al Mughirah Ibn Shaibah said “I got engaged to a woman at the time of
>   the Prophet (May Allah bless him and grant him peace). He asked me
>   “Have you seen her?” I said “No”. He said “go and have a look at her,
>   because it is more fitting that love and compatibility is established
>   between you.” (Nasai) - See more at:
>   http://www.therevival.co.uk/forced-arranged-love-secret-marriages#sthash.7RGlJhRY.dpuf

and

> Khansa Bint Khidam said “My father married me to his nephew, and I did
>   not like this match, so I complained to the Messenger of Allah (May
>   Allah bless him and grant him peace). He said to me “accept what your
>   father has arranged.” I said “I do not wish to accept what my father
>   has arranged.”
>
> He said “then this marriage is invalid, go and marry whomever you
>   wish.” I said “I have accepted what my father has arranged, but I
>   wanted women to know that fathers have no right in their daughter’s
>   matters (i.e. they have no right to force a marriage on them). (Fathul
>   Bari Sharah Al Bukhari 9/194, Ibn Majah Kitabun Nikah 1/602)
>   - See more at: http://www.therevival.co.uk/forced-arranged-love-secret-marriages#sthash.7RGlJhRY.dpuf

you can see in the last one that the Prophet (May Allah bless him and grant him peace) told Al Khansa to obey her father, and this is as it should be, because the concerns of fathers for the well being of their daughters is well known. But when she insisted about the being forced to marry he gave her the freedom to marry whoever she wanted as a forced marriage being invalid.
I'am from Tunisia (very similar culture to Morocco) and I can tell you that this law is a shame in North Africa, (unfortunately only in Morocco as far as I know) and that it is rather an exception than a general rule. I think now that it was brought to the medias, it won't last for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not part of Islamic Law.These people following there culture as Islam.As you know this is a law they have inherited from previous people of the book.

> **Deuteronomy 22:28-29** “If a man meets a virgin who is not betrothed, and seizes her and lies with her, and they are found, then
>   the man who lay with her shall give to the father of the young woman
>   fifty shekels of silver, and she shall be his wife, because he has
>   violated her. He may not divorce her all his days."
>
> **Exodus 22:16-17** “If a man seduces a virgin who is not betrothed and
>   lies with her, he shall give the bride price for her and make her his
>   wife. If her father utterly refuses to give her to him, he shall pay
>   money equal to the bride price for virgins"

Like this you will find Muslims doing things(**e:g : Killing apostates**) from Bible but not Supported by Quran. They are better followers of Bible.